# Pagination view in web pages

Tags: java, html, jsp, web

I have a query. I am using JSP with tomcat for web development. I have a set of values which have been retrieved from database as a list. Now, I want to show the values one by one on a page with a next button. How this can be done? Do we make multiple pages or dynamically refresh the page with new value on pressing next button? Could some one please guide me on this?

Answer (score 0):

if I'm not wrong, JSP does not provide any build in  pagination control. you can use pagination through javascript, or create you own control for pagination. here is a [link](http://www.javaworkspace.com/paginationUsingJavaScript.do) which might will you in pagination with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Tell me one thing, you are going to pick the records from database. So this is all dynamic data. So approach 1 is a big NO NO.

You should be dynamically refreshing, the page with Next button pointing to the next record  to display. But don't you think having a single record to display in a page, can make a UI experience bad.

UI should be simple yet cover most information, so rather go for the standard solution with list of records in a table like format with action link to view details for each record which will point me to the desired record detailed page. In actual this detailed page will just be one, but displaying dynamic data.

You can have a look at [Datatable in JQuery](http://www.datatables.net/) for pagination ofcourse.